# How to implement KNN using Matlab and calculate the percentage accuracy

Tags: matlab, matrix, percentage, knn

I'm new using matlab, my goal is to implement knn, I have two differents txt files, one contains test data(sample) and the other one contains training data.

So far I think I should do something like this, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
load fisheriris 
x = meas(:,3:4);
gscatter(x(:,1),x(:,2),species)
newpoint = [5 1.45];
[n,d] = knnsearch(x,newpoint,'k',10);
line(x(n,1),x(n,2),'color',[.5 .5 .5],'marker','o','linestyle','none','markersize',10)
```

Or maybe this is a more simple way to do it, to me that's very clear the two different sets of data, sample and training, but this doesn't show the accuracy of the predicted class.

```
 A= [50, 60;
    7,2;
    13,12;
    100,200;];
B=[1,0;
    200,30;
    19,10];
G={'First Row';
    'Second Row';
    'Third Row'};
class = knnclassify(A,B,G);

disp('Result: ');
disp(class);
```

the matrix looks like this:

```
Training data:
148.0,50.0,0
187.0,34.0,0
204.0,89.0,0
430.0,161.0,1
427.0,22.0,1
-42.0,469.0,1
more,more,class....

Test data:
290.0,-57.0,0
194.0,-80.0,0
174.0,33.0,0
465.0,691.0,1
270.0,-194.0,1
-56.0,665.0,1
more,more,class....
```

How can I classify this data using knn and show the predictions for each row so I can calculate the accuracy percentage?

```
-------EDITED------
```

I forgot, if I need the accuracy for each class, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated code using `knnclassify`

```
trainData= [148.0,50.0,0; ...
            187.0,34.0,0; ...
            204.0,89.0,0; ...
            430.0,161.0,1; ...
            427.0,22.0,1; ...
            -42.0,469.0,1 ...
            ];

testData=   [290.0,-57.0,0; ...
            194.0,-80.0,0; ...
            174.0,33.0,0; ...
            465.0,691.0,1; ...
            270.0,-194.0,1; ...
            -56.0,665.0,1];

% Data
Sample=testData(:,1:2);
Training=trainData(:,1:2);
Group=trainData(:,3);

% Classify
k=1;  % number of nearest neighbors used in the classification
Class = knnclassify(Sample, Training, Group,k);

% Display Prediction
fprintf('%.1f %.1f - Real %d , Predicted %d\n',[testData.'; Class.']);

% Calculate percentage accuracy for each class
trueClass=testData(:,3);
classList=unique(trueClass);
for classIndex=1:length(classList)
    indexesOfEachClass=find(trueClass==classList(classIndex));
    percentageAccuracyEachClass(classIndex,1)=sum(Class(indexesOfEachClass)==trueClass(indexesOfEachClass))/length(indexesOfEachClass)*100;
end
fprintf('\nClass %d Accuracy : %f%%',[classList.'; percentageAccuracyEachClass.']);

% Calculate overall percentage accuracy 
dataClassifiedAccurately=Class==trueClass;
percentageAccuracy=sum(dataClassifiedAccurately)/length(dataClassifiedAccurately)*100;
fprintf('\n\nOverall Accuracy : %f%%\n',percentageAccuracy);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally get it now.

Comment: If I need to apply ENN Rule, what should I do?
there is an image with pseudo code:
http://i.imgur.com/axyD7ms.png
would it work if I take the training set and find the biggest distance as well as the shortest and then divided by the number of rows.

And finally find the nearest neighbor with new edited set of training data?

Comment: I have updated the answer with percentage accuracy for each class. Next about ENN Rule. Please ask that as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, Your is code very clear so is easy to understand. I think that the key to find accuracy for each class is to use the index.